# Can Python class attributes be additive?

Tags: python, list, inheritance

I have a project with the following class structure:

```
class A(object):
    elems = [1, 2, 3]

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    elems = [20, 100]

class D(B):
    elems = [4, 5]
```

Currently, Python's default inheritance behaviour is to overwrite the `elems` attribute in each subsequent attribute declaration, e.g.:

```
A.elems == [1, 2, 3]
B.elems == [1, 2, 3]
C.elems == [20, 100]
D.elems == [4, 5]
```

I would like to be able to access an *additive* list of these values. In other words, I would like to be able to retrieve the following lists:

```
A.collated() == [1, 2, 3]
B.collated() == [1, 2, 3]
C.collated() == [1, 2, 3, 20, 100]
D.collated() == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I don't know how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
- B

Comment: Are you sure you actually want these to be class members (and for `collated` to be a `@classmethod`)? Because this is kind of an odd design—the kind of thing that's completely appropriate in Javascript, but rarely so in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to just be explicit:

```
class A(object):
    elems = [1, 2, 3]
    @classmethod
    def collated(cls):
      return sorted(cls.elems)

class B(A):
    pass

class C(B):
    elems = B.elems + [20, 100]

class D(B):
    elems = B.elems + [4, 5]

print "A.collated() == ", A.collated()
print "B.collated() == ", B.collated()
print "C.collated() == ", C.collated()
print "D.collated() == ", D.collated()
```

There *are* tricky things you could do to make this more automatic, but I don't think you want to. (If you think you want to, first go read up on how either descriptors or metaclasses work, then come back with specific questions.)

Comment: Someday I'll figure out what is going on with metaclasses ... (that's what I said about descriptors too -- eventually I got around to figuring those out ;)

Comment: @mgilson they're actually not too bad - stick to class decorators where possible is generally good though (and headache tablets) metametaclasses are fun though :)

Comment: @mgilson: If you haven't learned metaclasses yet, I'd wait until you're ready to go all-3.x and learn the "simplified" version. Especially if they're going to change them again in 3.4 or 3.5.

Comment: @abarnert -- Is changing them something that has been suggested?

Comment: @JonClements: If you're going to modify a class definition with `bytecodehacks`, it's a lot harder with a decorator than a metaclass. :)

Comment: @mgilson: There was some talk about finding a way to get back part of the 2.x functionality that's been lost in 3.x, although I don't know how far that went. I think really all people want 90% of the time is to change the class `__dict__` to a different type…

Comment: @abarnert I thought that could be done with `__prepare__` anyway

Comment: Thanks. I had indeed gone down the road of using metaclasses and decorators to solve this problem, but that took me so deep into the woods that I thought, "There must be an easier way". :)

Comment: @abarnert Could you link to some document listing the changes to metaclasses in Python3? I thought the only thing that changed was the syntax to specifying them and a quick google search and skimming through the "What's new in Python3" document doesn't bring up anything.

Comment: @Jon Perfect, unlikely that I'll ever do anything more with metaclasses than the simplest things (and even those very rarely), but still I like to know the ins and outs of the used programming language.

Comment: @JonClements: That was my point, I think `__prepare__` takes away 90% of people's need for 3.x metaclasses, so there's less motivation to change anything.

Comment: +1 for this anyway - as the OP was kind of asking for a class method approach... I just went the direct attribute approach...

Answer (score 3):

Just be explicit and access the class instance of the parent you want to extend...

```
class A(object):
    elems = [1, 2, 3]

class B(A):
    elems = A.elems # or pass

class C(B):
    elems = B.elems + [20, 100]

class D(B):
    elems = B.elems + [4, 5]

print A.elems, B.elems, C.elems, D.elems
# [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3, 20, 100] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```